# Unable to read files from internal storage in android application?

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have created one application to create and read the text file from internal and external storage. Text file creation is done successfully in external as well as internal storage. Reading file from external storage is also working but facing issue while reading file from internal storage and Getting error "Error occurred when getting file Content: FileName.txt"

Please see the below code:

//MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private String filename = "StorageFile.txt";
private String filepath = "FileStorage";
File myInternalFile;
File myExternalFile;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(
            getApplicationContext());
File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context. MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    myInternalFile = new File(directory, filename);

Button saveToInternalStorage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InternalStorageSave);
    saveToInternalStorage.setOnClickListener(this);

Button readFromInternalStorage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.InternalStorageGet);
    readFromInternalStorage.setOnClickListener(this);

Button saveToExternalStorage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ExternalStorageSave);
    saveToExternalStorage.setOnClickListener(this);

Button readFromExternalStorage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ExternalStorageGet);
    readFromExternalStorage.setOnClickListener(this);

    // check if external storage is available and not read only
    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        saveToExternalStorage.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
    }

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    EditText myInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputText);
    TextView responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
    String myData = "";

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.InternalStorageSave:
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(myInputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myInputText.setText("");
    responseText.setText("Saved to Internal Storage.(StorageFile.txt)");
        break;

    case R.id.InternalStorageGet:
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myData = myData + strLine;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myInputText.setText(myData);
        responseText
        .setText("Data retrieved from Internal Storage.(StorageFile.txt)");
        openFile(myInternalFile);

        break;

    case R.id.ExternalStorageSave:
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
            fos.write(myInputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myInputText.setText("");
    responseText.setText("Saved to External Storage.(StorageFile.txt)");
        break;

    case R.id.ExternalStorageGet:
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myData = myData + strLine;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myInputText.setText(myData);
        responseText
        .setText("Data retrieved from Internal Storage.(StorageFile.txt)");
        openFile(myExternalFile);
        break;

    }
}

private void openFile(File file) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    final String ext = file.getName().substring(
            file.getName().indexOf(".") + 1);
    final String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

//activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Storage Demo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/InputText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:minLines="2"
    android:text="Internal and External Storage" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/InternalStorageSave"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Internal Storage(Save)" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/InternalStorageGet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Internal Storage(Display)" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ExternalStorageSave"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="External Storage(Save)" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ExternalStorageGet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="External Storage(Displays)" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/responseText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also I have added below permission to read and write file to external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Locat Output:

```
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): file:// Uri exposed through Intent.getData()
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): java.lang.Throwable: 
file:// Uri exposed through Intent.getData()
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at     
android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1597)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at 
android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2338)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at 
android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:7194)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at   
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1418)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at 
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at  android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult
(Activity.java:3384)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at android.app.Activity.startActivity
(Activity.java:3626)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at  
com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onIntentSelected(ResolverActivity.java:407)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at  
com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.startSelected(ResolverActivity.java:299)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at 
com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onButtonClick(ResolverActivity.java:289)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at       
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944):at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
 (Handler.java:733)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
 (Handler.java:95)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at android.app.ActivityThread.main
 (ActivityThread.java:4998)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative
 (Native  Method)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at    
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
 (ZygoteInit.java:593)
 12-27 02:20:22.795: E/StrictMode(944): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main
 (Native Method)
 12-27 02:20:22.815: I/ActivityManager(371): START u0 
 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///data/data/com.example.external/
  app_FileStorage/StorageFile.txt typ=text/plain \
  flg=0x3000000 cmp=com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity} from pid 944
 12-27 02:20:23.015: D/gralloc(49): Registering a buffer in the process that 
 created it.    This may cause memory ordering problems.
 12-27 02:20:23.015: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 12-27 02:20:23.015: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 12-27 02:20:23.015: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 12-27 02:20:23.025: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 12-27 02:20:23.025: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -480946759
 12-27 02:20:23.025: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES 
 error while  taking screenshot
 12-27 02:20:23.025: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 12-27 02:20:23.025: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
 12-27 02:20:23.025: W/WindowManager(371): Screenshot failure taking 
 screenshot for (328x546) to layer 21015
 12-27 02:20:23.805: D/dalvikvm(1133): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 2% free 
 6543K/6656K, paused 77ms, total 92ms
 12-27 02:20:24.545: W/AwContents(1133): nativeOnDraw failed; 
 clearing to background color.
 12-27 02:20:24.625: I/Choreographer(944): Skipped 153 frames!  
 The application may be doing    too much work on its main thread.
 12-27 02:20:25.795: W/AwContents(1133): nativeOnDraw failed; 
 clearing to background color.
 12-27 02:20:25.945: I/ActivityManager(371): Displayed   
 com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity: +2s834ms
  12-27 02:20:25.945: I/Choreographer(371): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may 
   be     doing too much work on its main thread.
 12-27 02:20:26.165: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(1133): Unable to open content URL:      
   content: //com.android.htmlfileprovider/data/data/com.example.external/
 app_FileStorage/StorageFile.txt?text/plain
```

Can you please tell me how to read file from internal storage?

Regards,
Shainaz

Comment: Please add logcat output

Comment: what do mean by internal storage, data/data directory or internal memory(phone storage)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
try {

    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

            openFileInput("DayTwentyTwoFile")));

    String inputString;

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                

    while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {

        stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");

    }

    lblTextViewOne.setText(stringBuffer.toString());

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: Reading and setting the text on label is working. Reading files from other android application like notepad, text editor is not working. How to set the permission for internal storage?

Comment: @user3138623 another app can not read file stored in your app's internal storage. For that you have to copy that file to external storage to make it world readable.

Comment: @Ketan most of the times mobile don't have external storage. So how to resolve this issue.

Comment: you have to check it that if there is memory card attached or not. and on the basis of result generate toast or something to acknowledge user that external storage is not present.

Answer (score 0):

i hope your saying about data\data directory files which are specific to any application. so if you want have an access to data\data files of any application that application should provide permissions for that in terms of content providers and permissions also if any specified for that.

If its internal storage then no issues you can read, write it with androidmanifest.xml permission below.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: I have already added the write permission still its not working